# Toggle Play and Pause Music React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, media-player

I try to play and pause music whit use only one button. When press the button the music starts to play, but when try pause the music something goes wrong. What are I doing wrong?

I get following Error:

*Possible unhandled Promise Rejection (id:0):
TypeError: Sound.pauseAsync is not a function.*

Here is my audio function

```
    const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
      { uri: props.songURL }
    );
      await Audio.setIsEnabledAsync(true);
      setSound(songs);
      setSongs(userSongPosts)
    if (isPlaying === true) {
        try {
            await sound.pauseAsync();
            setIsPlaying(false);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
          }
    } else {
        try {
            await sound.playAsync(); 
            setIsPlaying(true);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
          }
    }
  }
```

Here is my Button

```
        <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.profilContainer}
              onPress={() => playSound() }>
            <Text>{isPlaying ? 'Pause' : 'Play'}</Text>
            <View style={styles.buttonView}>
            <Text style={styles.textButton}>{props.submitText}</Text>
            <MatetrialCommunityIcons
              style={styles.iconStyles}
              name={props.icon}
            />
```

Comment: so what exactly is not working? do you get an error?

Comment: I cannot pause the music. I added my error message in my question, see update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest you to create a ref and store the sound varibale in that

[Working Example](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/audio-player)

Like this

```
const sound = React.useRef(new Audio.Sound());
const [Status, SetStatus] = React.useState(false);

React.useEffect(() => {
  LoadAudio();
  return () => sound.current.unloadAsync();
}, []);

const LoadAudio = async () => {
  const checkLoading = await sound.current.getStatusAsync();
  try {
    const result = await sound.current.loadAsync({ uri: Song }, {}, true);
    // Here Song is the uri of the Audio file
    if (result.isLoaded === false) {
      console.log('Error in Loading Audio');
    } else {
      PlayAudio();
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error in Loading Audio');
  }
};

  const LoadAudio = async () => {
    const checkLoading = await sound.current.getStatusAsync();
    try {
      const result = await sound.current.loadAsync({ uri: Song }, {}, true);
      if (result.isLoaded === false) {
        console.log('Error in Loading Audio');
      } else {
        PlayAudio();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error in Loading Audio');
    }
  };

  const PlayAudio = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await sound.current.getStatusAsync();
      if (result.isLoaded) {
        if (result.isPlaying === false) {
          sound.current.playAsync();
          SetStatus(true);
        }
      } else {
        LoadAudio();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      SetStatus(false);
    }
  };

  const PauseAudio = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await sound.current.getStatusAsync();
      if (result.isLoaded) {
        if (result.isPlaying === true) {
          sound.current.pauseAsync();
          SetStatus(false);
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      SetStatus(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{Status === false  ? 'Stopped' : 'Playing now'}</Text>
      <View style={{ width: '100%' }}>
        <Button title="Play Sound" onPress={() => PlayAudio()} />
        <Button title="Pause Sound" onPress={() => PauseAudio()} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
```

In this implementation there are two seperate buttons for `Pause` and `Play`. So if you want a `single` button to `toggle pause and play` then the `return` statement should look like this

```
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text>{Status === false ? 'Stopped' : 'Playing now'}</Text>
    <View style={{ width: '100%' }}>
      <Button
        title={Status === false ? 'Play' : 'Pause'}
        onPress={Status === false ? () => PlayAudio() : () => PauseAudio()}
      />
    </View>
  </View>
);
```

Don't forget the imports at the top like this

```
import * as React from "react";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Okey, so this should work if I only want to use one button, cause in this example they have two button?

Comment: You want to make it using one Button? I've added solution if you want to toggle it with single button.